# Cannot instantiate kind-polymorphic types

Tags: haskell, ghc, higher-kinded-types, type-kinds

The following code fails to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, KindSignatures, 
         MultiParamTypeClasses, PolyKinds, RankNTypes, 
         ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Prim

type family CtxOf d (args :: k) :: Constraint

class Run ctx (params :: [k]) where
  runAll :: Proxy ctx
            -> Proxy params
            -> (forall (args :: k) . (CtxOf ctx args) => Proxy args -> Bool)
            -> [Bool]

instance Run ctx '[] where
  runAll _ _ _ = []

data BasicCtxD
type instance CtxOf BasicCtxD '(a,b) = (a ~ b)
instance (Run BasicCtxD params, a ~ b) 
  => Run BasicCtxD ( '(a,b) ': params) where
  runAll pctx _ f = (f (Proxy::Proxy '(a,b))) : 
      (runAll pctx (Proxy::Proxy params) f)

wrap1Arg :: forall a b . (a ~ b) 
  => (Proxy '(a,b) -> Bool) -> Proxy '(a,b) -> Bool
wrap1Arg f = f

map1Arg :: (forall a (b :: k) . (a ~ b) => Proxy '(a,b) -> Bool) -> [Bool]
map1Arg g = runAll (Proxy::Proxy BasicCtxD) (Proxy::Proxy '[ '(Int,Int)]) $ wrap1Arg g
```

with the error

```
Could not deduce ((~) ((,) * *) args '(b0, b0))
from the context (CtxOf ((,) * *) BasicCtxD args)
  bound by a type expected by the context:
             CtxOf ((,) * *) BasicCtxD args => Proxy ((,) * *) args -> Bool
  at Main.hs:31:13-86
  ‘args’ is a rigid type variable bound by
         a type expected by the context:
           CtxOf ((,) * *) BasicCtxD args => Proxy ((,) * *) args -> Bool
         at Main.hs:31:13
Expected type: Proxy ((,) * *) args -> Bool
  Actual type: Proxy ((,) * *) '(b0, b0) -> Bool
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘wrap1Arg g’
In the expression:
  runAll (Proxy :: Proxy BasicCtxD) (Proxy :: Proxy '['(Int, Int)]) $ wrap1Arg g
```

I suspect that, like the [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11498#ticket) I just filed, I just need to poke GHC in the right way. It seems GHC thinks all of the *kinds* match up, but it's simply refusing to replace the polymorphic type `args :: (*,*)` with `'(b0,b0)`. Put another way, I think it's the kind-polymorphic equivalent of GHC complaining `Could not deduce a ~ Int` in this perfectly valid example:

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f = undefined

g = f (3 :: Int)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, `args :: (,) * *` does not mean that `args = '(a, b)` for some `a` and `b`, so the `type instance CtxOf BasicCtxD '(a,b) = (a ~ b)` clause is not known to apply. (...and so `g` can't be given a type as polymorphic as demanded by `runAll`, even if you `wrap1Arg` it.)

Comment: I think this error is perfectly valid - just because `args :: (a,b)` exists, does not mean that `exists (q :: a) (r :: b) . args ~ '(a,r)` because Haskells type systm is plainly inconsistent - trivially, we have `Any :: (*,*)`. Change `... (CtxOf ctx args) => Proxy args -> ...` to `(CtxOf ctx args) => Sing args -> ...` and then you can pattern match on the singleton, which *does* contain the proof that `args :: (a,b) ==> exists (q :: a) (r :: b) . args ~ '(a,r)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Hmm, I see. And there's no way to define the family instance as something more like `type instance CtxOf BasicCtxD (arg :: (*,*)) = (arg ~ '(a,b), (a ~ b))`, right? (That gives "`a` and `b` are not in scope").

Comment: I should also explain what types I want to use for `args`. I'm trying to use type pairs, triples, etc, so I'm trying to use kind-polymorphism rather than write several versions of `runAll` with different tuple sizes.

Comment: @user2407038 I looked into a singletons solution, but it wasn't clear to me how I would enforce constraints. Perhaps you could post a solution below to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure out a solution using GADTs to hide both the constraints and the variable number of parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, KindSignatures, 
             MultiParamTypeClasses, PolyKinds, RankNTypes, GADTs,
             ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Proxy

data family CtxOf ctx

class Run ctx (params :: [k]) where
  runAll :: Proxy params
            -> (CtxOf  ctx -> Bool) 
            -> [Bool]

instance Run ctx '[] where
  runAll _ _ = []


data BasicCtxD
data instance CtxOf BasicCtxD where BasicCtx :: (a ~ b) => Proxy '(a,b) -> CtxOf BasicCtxD
instance (Run BasicCtxD params, a ~ b) 
  => Run BasicCtxD ( ('(a,b)) ': params) where
  runAll _ f = (f $ BasicCtx (Proxy::Proxy '(a,b))) : 
      (runAll (Proxy::Proxy params) f)


wrap1Arg :: (forall a (b :: k) . (a ~ b) => Proxy '(a,b) -> Bool) -> CtxOf BasicCtxD -> Bool
wrap1Arg f (BasicCtx p) = f p

map1Arg :: (forall a (b :: k) . (a ~ b) => Proxy '(a,b) -> Bool) -> [Bool]
map1Arg g = runAll (Proxy::Proxy '[ '(Int,Int)]) $ wrap1Arg g
```

Essentially, the *type* family `CtxOf` became a *data* family. The idea is to make each instance of the family a GADT holding a constraint (that was previously defined by the type family), along with the existential types that would have gone in the type pair/triple/etc.